# How do I copy and paste all text from a microsoft word document into someplace else without grabbing text from comments?

Tags: microsoft-word

Ctrl+A, Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V will grab every comment and add it to the bottom of the text after a paste.

I'd like to keep my comments in my documents and be able to copy-paste the document text from place to place without having to worry about whether or not a comment I put in the document is going to pop up.

Is this possible?

Comment: Your wording — copy all text ***from*** a Microsoft Word document — puzzles me. Do you mean copy and paste text ***within*** a Microsoft Word document, or do you mean copy text ***from*** a Microsoft Word document and paste it *into* something else?  And, if it’s the latter, what is the destination? … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: @Scott - More Clear?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the paste context menu that appears after pasting something. If you do nothing afterwards, the menu disappears.

[image: word paste menu]

Comment: What if I'm pasting into a website text block?

Comment: Well if you want to paste into a website without pasting your comments, you must first paste into a blank word file to get the comments not pasted in. Then copy all of that.

Comment: That's... hacky but it does work : -/ I can live with that but I'm going to leave this unanswered unless I get nothing but crickets. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try ... <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> which should paste as plain text.

If you are pasting into a website using Chrome or Edge, those are the two browsers I tested the key sequence with under Windows, then this sequence works. You can also just right click on the text box using either of those two browsers and you should see this:

[image]

I am running Windows 10 and I cannot attest to what a non-current version of Windows accepts. And BTW ... if you are on a Mac, Safari does not accept that exact sequence.

Comment: In Microsoft Word, Ctrl+Shift+V is Paste Format. What are you talking about? … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: @Scott please see my editted answer. I believe you might not have read the entire posting including the OP's comment in the other answer in the thread.